# Largo de imagen CSS

Tags: html, css, css3, grid

Hola tenia una duda bastante breve que e estado bastante rato intentando solucionar y no se si alguien podría ayudar, resulta de que n**ecesito poner una imagen como banner para un video de YouTube pero la imagen se me duplica** por así decirlo **no ocupa el 100% del largo** acá dejo la clase con la cual estoy trabajando y el como se ve.

```
.banner-video{
background-image: url(../img/banner-transparencia-activa-2018.png) ;
padding: 200px 150px;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```

}

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agrega a tu css las otras propiedades para background:

```
.banner-video{
  background-image: url(../img/banner-transparencia-activa-2018.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat; /* evita que se repita la imagen */
  background-size: 100%; /* usa el 100% del largo de la pantalla */
  padding: 200px 150px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por la ayuda, esta fue la solución.

Comment: @BryanJoséM79 recuerda marcarla como respuesta